# Row manipulation in files, bash

Tags: bash, awk, grep, file-manipulation

I have a file called SSH which contains two lines of information. It looks like this:

```
src=192.168.60.111 ttl: 64 last_seen: 4295187854 oldest_pkt: 16 4295157111, 4295168442, 4295172078, 4295172078, 4295172328, 4295172328, 4295172829, 4295172829, 4295173830, 4295173830, 4295175834, 4295175834, 4295179838, 4295179838, 4295187854, 4295187854
src=10.0.98.2 ttl: 64 last_seen: 4295868429 oldest_pkt: 16 4295845135, 4295848540, 4295851694, 4295851694, 4295853197, 4295853197, 4295856201, 4295856201, 4295859226, 4295859226, 4295862420, 4295862420, 4295865425, 4295865425, 4295868429, 4295868429
```

I want to make a script which controlls weather the last_seen number + number of packets sent * 10 is smaller than current time.
for example: if($currenttime >= 4295187854+16*10) for the first line.
IF current time is bigger, the line should be removed.
It is a try to make a delay on the login via SSH and the SSH-file notes every IP that has written wrong password more than 3 times.

I am very new to scripting and tried solve this with awk but did not make any progress. Do you guys have any idea of how I can scan the file line by line, analyze the different fields and depending on answer from the if-statement remove it?

**EDIT**
This is what i produced, this probably doesn't make any sense since i can't understand what's actually going on with awk.

```
#!/bin/sh
currenttime=$(date +%s)
awk  '{if ($currenttime >= $5+10*$7) print $0 > "temp.txt";}' SSH
cp -f temp.txt SSH
rm temp.txt
```

Comment: But what is the `10` factor that you are multiplying with `16`?

Comment: I have edited the question with my "script". the 10 is just hardcoded, i figured 10 seconds is enough! @Inian

Comment: Is that 16 from `$7`?

Comment: exactly, i assume " " is the delimiter by default. @JamesBrown

Comment: $5+10*$7 where $5 = 4295187854 and $7 = 16, which means 4295187854 + 160, that is not 687338948640. Multiplication is always before addition ^^ @Inian

Comment: @Louise: Even then the date says `Wed, 17 Feb 2106 16:49:49 GMT` a 90-year difference? Are you sure your conditions are right? If you have `EPOCH` less than this, all your lines for next 90 years will match,

Comment: I have not connected my system to an NTP-server, this is just a test case, nothing going in production.. @Inian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
$ awk 'strftime("%s")<=$5+$7*10' SSH
```

`strftime("%s")` returns *The time as a decimal timestamp in seconds since the epoch* which is compared against the `$5+$7*10`. If the comparison is `true` record is printed.

**Edit**: Thank you @EdMorton for pointing out that the `%s` specifier is not supported by all systems (see Gnu awk [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) on the issue) and on those unsupported systems `systime()` should be used instead (it's shorter so just use it on all systems anyway!):

```
awk 'systime()<=$5+$7*10' SSH
```

Comment: Current time works fine, but i dont know if awk scans only the first line or "loops" through all lines.

Comment: It processes every line (well, every _record_ which by default is a line) in the file.

Comment: Then i guess the only problem is that $0 takes the whole file and not the current line, do you know how to access the current line?

Comment: @Louise Sorry, I didn't understand. Awk processes every line (or record) in the file and `$0` is the current record awk is processing.

Comment: Thank you for your information and help. I was just confused over awk. I just had to add a "touch temp.txt" in the beginning, because if all if-statements are false, there are no temp.txt to work with. @JamesBrown

Comment: Remark for extra use: if file was huge (not the case with this 2 line like OP specify), use maybe a variable fixing the time at start, especially if file is feed very quickly like often with huge file. Once more, quick and good script

Comment: Huh? `strftime()` formats a timestamp but `%s` isn't a time format so it would return a null string. You mean `systime()` and you'd use it as `awk 'BEGIN{now=systime()} now<=$5+$7*10' SSH`. And yet it's the accepted answer - baffling...